# How to create an empty VIEW in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I am trying to create an empty VIEW in mySQL with the columns I define.

i.e. I would like a view with columns: age, id, gender, but with 0 rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A view doesn't have rows, the resultset it references does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example for you:

```
mysql> create or replace view v_test as 
    -> select 99 as age, 
    ->   2147483647 as id, 
    ->   'F' as gender 
    -> from dual 
    -> where false;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> desc v_test;
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| age    | int(2)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| id     | bigint(10) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| gender | varchar(1) | NO   |     |         |       |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from v_test;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Nice `where false`. Or `where 1 <> 1` in another dialect

Answer (score 7):

Why you would ever want to do this is beyond me:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT NULL AS age, NULL AS id, NULL AS gender WHERE FALSE
```

Comment: Maybe the question should have been:  How do I... and why?  That would have been more interesting to try and answer.

Comment: oh, I bet I know... test case.

Comment: If you want to use this view later in a left or full join, and programmatically want to ensure the view exists with the right columns, even though it doesn't always need to have data. e.g. if you are using `ISNULL` / `COALESCE` / `NVL` or some function like that on these columns.

Comment: +1. One scenario where this is useful is stubbing out a View built by a query to another server. If you're exporting a DB's schema script to put together a local integration testing DB, you don't want that DB hitting the server. Easier to stub it out than delete it and all other references.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your view from this select statement:

```
SELECT 5 as age, 10 as id, 'M' as gender
WHERE age = 0
```

This will give you the correct types for the columns